# WD External hard drive usb plug pushed in

Tags: usb, hard-drive

Just want to know if my hard drive is fixable please? Accidentally pushed in the USB port as you can tell by the picture. I hope just need to get a new one put on? Well the little USB bit and a silver part that was a part of it came off loose nothing at all looks damaged though? Oh its not a portable one so when I plug in power cord still get a signal.

[image]

Comment: How can we tell if we don't see the picture? Please include a link to a picture and someone will edit it in.

Comment: Hi sorry posted a link on the facebook page and copied and pasted thanks :)

Comment: From the looks of it someone with a proper soldering iron and some electronics knowledge might be able to put the connector back.

Comment: Thanks for that guys just joined the site as i get very frustrated with my computer when your not quiet sure about something, just wanted to make sure it will still work cos my partner will kill me when hes home wish the ports were tougher :)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you not to try to fix it. It seems that the pcb is damaged. It is better to change the adapter instead of frying your motherboard

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be fixed. Depending on how the pins on the usb connector are, you could just solder it back on, or you might need a new one. One catch, the first pin on the left, which should be usb power, the trace has broken off. A bit of wire will need to be used to connect that pin on the usb connector, to another point on the same trace (the left side of resistor R40). Anyone with moderate experience with a soldering iron could do it.

The other thing is that piece of metal clip. Not sure where it goes or how it was attached. It might be to ground the hard drive to the usb shield. In that case, it would go on top of the usb connector, and touches the hard drive metal. But you would need to double check.

The other option is simply getting another usb hard drive adaptor.